# DSE 5.0.11 installation on CentOS 7

Tags: cassandra, centos7, datastax, cassandra-3.0

While i am trying to install DSE 5.0.11 on machine CentOS 7.4, I am getting dependency issue as below.

```
Error: Package: dse-full-5.0.11-1.noarch (/dse-full-5.0.11-1.noarch)
       Requires: dse-libpig = 5.0.11
```

But I believe the support for pig is completely removed from Cassandra for newer versions (3.0) which in turn implies that DSE 5.0.11 uses Cassandra 3.0.14

---

I tried using this command for local install.

```
sudo yum localinstall /tmp/5.0.11/dse-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-demos-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-full-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libcassandra-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libgraph-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libhive-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-liblog4j-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libmahout-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libsolr-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libspark-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libsqoop-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libtomcat-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libhadoop-5.0.11-1.noarch.rpm /tmp/5.0.11/dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.11-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Also I tried, using --skip-broken and it seems it's not going to install as below.

```
Skipped (dependency problems):
 dse                                   noarch                              
5.0.11-1                                       /dse-5.0.11-1.noarch                                                         
110 M
 dse-demos                                                   noarch                                       
5.0.11-1                                       /dse-demos-5.0.11-
1.noarch                                                    75 M
 dse-full                                                    noarch                                       
5.0.11-1                                       /dse-full-5.0.11-
1.noarch                                                     90 k
```

Can i go ahead and use --skip-broken (or) how can i tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DSE 5.1 installer that is found here.

[DSE Install Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/install/installTOC.html)

The file you'll download is a .run file named

> DataStaxEnterprise-5.1.5-linux-x64-installer.run

And yes, DSE 5.1 is based on Cassandra 3.0. If you have broken or missing dependencies you should address those first.

Hope this helps

Comment: I updated the link and it should work now. The original link was a direct link to the installer, this one that works is a level up so you will need to click into the Installer page.